# Enumerate List<enum> with Reflection C#

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I'm trying to auto generate a UI with default values from a Class. But I am unable to get the values in the lists if they are enum base types.

I've created a test example below of what I'm trying to do. But I cannot figure out how to access the data from inside the lists, when they are not type "object" but type "enum"

What I don't want to add is a switch case statements for all possible enums list combinations.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var options = new Options();
        
        options.Foods = new List<Food>() {Food.Chips, Food.Pie};
        options.Drinks = new List<Drink>() {Drink.Lemonade,Drink.Water};
        
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in options.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
            object vals = propertyInfo.GetValue(options);
            var type = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            
            Console.WriteLine(type);
            

// Error is here, how can I loop through a enum list without 
// hard coding in each List<enum> type. 

            foreach(var item in vals as IEnumerable<object>)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--" + item.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
    
}


public class Options
{
    public List<Food> Foods {get;set;}
    public List<Drink> Drinks {get;set;}
}


public enum Food
{
    Chips,
    Fish,
    Burger,
    Pie,
    Mash
    
}

public enum Drink
{
    Cola,
    Lemonade,
    Water
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add using System.Collections;

not using System.Collections.Generic;

This allowed use if IEnumerable without a type definition.